# Why minitest case are failing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

## MyModel class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_presence_of :value
 ...
end
```

## my post.yml

```
one:
  row: 2
  col: 3
  name: 'Test'
```

## MyTest cases

```
require 'test_helper'
class SimulationsModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

def setup
 @post = Post.new
end

test 'post must have name' do
 @post.name = ' '
 assert @post.valid?
end
```

end

Why this above test cases are failing? However following test cases are passing

```
test 'post must have name' do
@post.name = ' '
assert_not @post.valid?
```

end

In my model I don't have `presence => true` set for name, Then why first test case are failing?

## Edit-1

What if I have two `validates_presence of : value , :name`. My test cases is:

```
test 'post must have name' do
 @post.name = 'some'
 @post.value = 'test'
 assert @post.valid?
end
```

It must pass the test cases but it's failing. I don't have any other required parameters in `models`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `@post` will be valid only when it has a `value`, and in your test you only assign a `name` to it.

In your model:

```
validates_presence_of :value
```

You don't assign `value`. You don't do `@post.value = 'some_value'` anywhere.

Edit:

The `:` before means its a symbol representing the attribute name. You can define validation for multiple fields this way:

```
validates_presence_of :value, :name
```

Comment: Thanks @piotr for explaining. Can you please help me or give a suggestion : How to write a test for `before_create` method in model class?

Comment: Testing callbacks is a pain, that's why a lot of developers don't use them. It's an extensive subject, research it a bit and then ask another question.

Comment: could you please check the `Edit` section of queston

Comment: Oh! Sorry It was a typo mistake ...I just updated it